# Lift tracking a logged in user

Tags: java, scala, session-state, lift

I have a sitemap defined like this in Boot.scala

```
   def sitemap() = SiteMap(
      Menu(S ? "Home") / "index",
      Menu(S ? "Login") / "login",
      Menu(S ? "Do Logged in Stuff") / "loggedinstuff"  >> If( () => loggedInUser.is != Empty, "You must be logged in") )
```

Also I have a loggedInUser defined in Boot.scala like this

```
object loggedInUser extends SessionVar[Box[String]](Empty)
```

When I have a user log in, I want them to change my loggedInUser to be the username that they successfully logged in as.

- Is this an okay way to deal with logging in users?
- Where should I keep my loggedInUser object. Boot.scala? Somewhere else?
- How do I update loggedInUser so that he will now work to show the "loggedinstuff" page?

Comment: Did you have a look at the file ProtoUser.scala in the Lift sources? ProtoUser provides more or less the same features so you can see how it’s done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by doing like here

[Scala and Lift and SessionVar that loses it contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052682/scala-and-lift-and-sessionvar-that-loses-it-contents)

Made this object

```
object SessionState {

   object loggedInUserName extends SessionVar[Box[String]](Empty)
}
```

and then did

```
SessionState.loggedInUserName(Full(username))
```